# Write a random value in a cell if the cell has the same value that can be found in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

I have the below two sheets in an excel file. I need a VBA code that will write in the column Status the value "Completed" but only if the ID is found in Sheet2. So for example, in Sheet1 I want the ID 1 to be with status "Completed", but ID 2 with blank cell in Status, because ID2 cannot be found in Sheet2. I would like to do this with a for each, as it will work faster than a simple IF formula, but I can't seem to find a code that would work. Thank you

```
Sheet1:
----------------------------------
ID |  Product | Date      | Status
-----------------------------------
1  |   abc    | 05-Jan-19 |
2  |   abc    | 07-Jan-18 |
3  |   def    | 05-Apr-19 |
4  |   ghi    | 06-Feb-19 |
```

```
Sheet2:
-------------
ID | Product  
-------------
1  | abc       
3  | def     
4  | ghi
```

Comment: You can do this with a simple COUNTIF or MATCH formula.

Comment: formula would be sufficient here, why do you need VBA?

Comment: It's part of a complex VBA code, it's one step that I need to do and it needs to be done fast..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array is fast.

```
Sub setStatus()
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Set Ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set Ws2 = Sheets(2)

    With Ws1
        vDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With Ws2
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, vDB(i, 1)) Then
            vR(i, 1) = "Completed"
        End If
    Next i
    Ws1.Range("d2").Resize(n) = vR
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A4;Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6;0));"";"Completed")
```

- A4 is a cell in Status column from Sheet1
- $A$2:$A$6 is the range of ids from Sheet2.

Just apply this formula to all cells in Status column from Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

I made the code with the assumption that both ranges start from A1. Please, test it!

```
Sub BringVal()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, arrCheck As Variant, arrMatch As Variant
 Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arrRez As Variant
 Dim boolF As Boolean
   Set sh1 = Sheets(1): Set sh2 = Sheets(2) 'use here your real sheets!
   lastRow1 = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   lastRow2 = sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

   arrCheck = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow1).Value
   arrMatch = sh2.Range("A2:B" & lastRow2).Value
   ReDim arrRez(1 To UBound(arrCheck))
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrCheck)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrMatch, 1)
            If arrCheck(i, 1) = arrMatch(j, 1) Then
                boolF = True
                arrRez(i) = arrMatch(j, 2): Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not boolF Then arrRez(i) = Empty
   Next i
   If UBound(arrRez) > 0 _
        Then sh1.Range("D2:D" & UBound(arrRez) + 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrRez)
End Sub
```

The code should be extremely fast, since it works only in memory and drop all the collected data at once.
If you need a message for the case of not any match found, it is so easy to add an `Else ... End If` sequence after the last `If`...

Answer (score 0):

**TheReddsable** you can try below code also

```
Option Explicit

Dim awb, product_id As String
Dim sht_1_count, sht_2_count, loop_i, loop_d As Double


Sub get_status()

awb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
sht_1_count = Workbooks(awb).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht_2_count = Workbooks(awb).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For loop_i = 2 To sht_1_count

        product_id = Workbooks(awb).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(loop_i, 1)

    For loop_d = 2 To sht_2_count

        If LCase(Trim(product_id)) = LCase(Trim(Workbooks(awb).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(loop_d, 1))) Then

            Workbooks(awb).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(loop_i, 4) = "Completed"
            Exit for
        End If
    Next loop_d

Next loop_i

End Sub
```